# mount mdadm disk without partition table

Tags: linux, mount, raid, mdadm

I've a `debian` installation and during the installation I had made 3 `mdadm` raid disk: `swap`, `root` and `home`. I had done it with partman and it had made the `mdadm` disk without `partition table`.
Now I want to install `Arch Linux` next to `debian`, I've manually made a `mdadm` disk (in a free space) and made a `msdos` partiton table.
The configuration is this:

```
lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0 651,9G  0 part  
│ └─md1         9:1    0 651,8G  0 raid1 /home
├─sda2          8:2    0  16,8G  0 part  
│ └─md2         9:2    0  33,5G  0 raid0 [SWAP]
├─sda3          8:3    0 131,4G  0 part  
│ └─md3         9:3    0 262,6G  0 raid0 /
└─sda4          8:4    0 131,4G  0 part  
  └─md127       9:127  0 262,6G  0 raid0 
    └─md127p1 259:0    0 262,6G  0 md    
sdb             8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0 651,9G  0 part  
│ └─md1         9:1    0 651,8G  0 raid1 /home
├─sdb2          8:18   0  16,8G  0 part  
│ └─md2         9:2    0  33,5G  0 raid0 [SWAP]
├─sdb3          8:19   0 131,4G  0 part  
│ └─md3         9:3    0 262,6G  0 raid0 /
└─sdb4          8:20   0 131,4G  0 part  
  └─md127       9:127  0 262,6G  0 raid0 
    └─md127p1 259:0    0 262,6G  0 md
```

`md127` is the disk where I want to install Arch. The problem is that in the Arch live I can only mount `md127p1` because is in a partition table, but I can't mount the others partitions.
I've tried with
`mdadm --assemble /dev/md3 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sda3` but the raid appears to be already assembled.
How can I mount these disks that doesn't have a partition table in the Arch live?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just mount `/dev/md1` (your `/home` on your Debian installation) and `/dev/md3` (your `/` on your Debian installation), *e.g.* by doing

```
mount /dev/md3 /mnt
mount /dev/md1 /mnt/home
```

(if you're running a live-CD system there may already be things mounted on `/mnt`, but you can use another directory).